# DateTime Catchable fatal error

Tags: php

I have a problem, i'm a beginnner
I have a birthday date (in the format Y-m-d)
And I have the actually date.

```
$date = $_POST["DatumJJJJ"]."-".$_POST["DatumMM"]."-".$_POST["DatumTT"];
$birthday = new DateTime($date);
$now = new DateTime(date("Y-m-d"));
$difference = $birthday->diff($now);
echo $difference;
```

Now, theres an error in the last line:

```
Catchable fatal error: Object of class DateInterval could not be converted to string
```

What should I do? I saw other similar questions but they don't help me!

Comment: look the structure of dateInterval obect http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php

Comment: this is because `$difference` is object of try `$difference->format('%R%a days');` for more detail have a look at http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because `$difference` is not a string. You cannot print it directly like you print string. If you want to see the data contained by `$difference`. Use [print_r()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php). Like this,

```
print_r($difference);
```

Output of the above function would be something like this,

```
DateInterval Object
(
    [y] => 0
    [m] => 7
    [d] => 29
    [h] => 0
    [i] => 0
    [s] => 0
    [weekday] => 0
    [weekday_behavior] => 0
    [first_last_day_of] => 0
    [invert] => 0
    [days] => 242
    [special_type] => 0
    [special_amount] => 0
    [have_weekday_relative] => 0
    [have_special_relative] => 0
)
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php for detailed information of each key within object.

Comment: Thank you but now I have an other problem

Comment: I have tried `$difference->format(Y);` and `$difference->format(Y-M-D);`
but it dosn't work. I want only years, months and days

Comment: You can get it like this: `$difference->y`, `$difference->m` and `$difference->d`.